# Bot not pushing top users

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So as I was finishing to update my bot to V12 I notice that the top 10 users are not shwoing up. I would also like to change it so that it is not global users but it is users within the server. But I have no idea how to do so. Within the code it seems to not show any errors but I am still unsure why it will not push the top users.

Here is the code

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const { prefix } = require("../../botconfig.json");
const db = require('quick.db')
let bal = require('../../database/balance.json');

module.exports = {
  config:{
    name: "rich",
    aliases: ["leader"],
    category: "economy",
    description: "Tells who is rich",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
  },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

      let board = [];
  for(let key of Object.keys(bal)){
    let value = Object.assign({user: client.users.cache.get(key)}, bal[key]);
    board.push(value);

  board = board.filter(x => x.user);
  board = board.sort((a,b) => b.balance-a.balance).splice(0, 10);
  top = board.map((x, i) => `${i+1}  ${x.user.username}\n     Balance: ${x.balance.toLocaleString()}`).join('\n\n');
  let embed = new MessageEmbed() 
  .setColor("RANDOM") 
  .setDescription(`** | Top 10 Global Rich User\n\n**${top}`);

  return message.channel.send(embed);

  }
    }
}
```

Again as stated above there is no errors but it is not pushing top users and I would like to change it to it gets the richest players within the server.

Comment: So I found the error to the code I just had to delete the code and pate it back in for it to begin working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reply to your wish about getting top 10 users within the server :

You could do the following :

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    // Get all members of the server before doing anything
    message.guild.members.fetch().then(guildMembers => {
        let board = [];

        for (let key of Object.keys(bal)) {
            // Checks if the collection of GuildMembers contains the key.
            if (guildMembers.has(key)) {
                let value = Object.assign({user: guildMembers.get(key).user}, bal[key]);
                board.push(value);
            }
        }

        board = board.sort((a,b) => b.balance-a.balance).splice(0, 10);
        let top = board.map((x, i) => `${i+1}  ${x.user.username}\nBalance: ${x.balance.toLocaleString()}`).join('\n\n');
        let embed = new MessageEmbed() 
        .setColor("RANDOM") 
        .setDescription(`** | Top 10 Global Rich User\n\n**${top}`);

        return message.channel.send(embed);
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Okay so I added that in with how it looks but I get an error that says TypeError: Cannot read property ‘toLocaleString’ of undefined. The code that gets people that are members of the server is obove ```for(let key``` did I do something wrong or do I need to delete something for it to work?

Comment: I am really sorry, I just realized that my code was completely bad, I edited my answer by adding full code, fixed errors and made little optimization. All the code you wrote have to be wrap in the `.then()` callback.